# Best way to clone a github repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

Ok so here's the scenario.

I made a pretty bad newbie mistake.  I was working on some code and didn't create a dev branch to checkout and test in development.  So I've made all of these changes to the master branch on my machine that are still broken (in development) and my boss wants me to make some changes to the app in production.

My thoughts on how to do this was:

1. Rename my project's directory so I have a backup of it
2. git clone the last remote version back onto my machine
3. Make the slight changes he wants and re-deploy/commit
4. Sort out what I've changed in my old version of the app and bring it into a dev branch into the newly cloned master branch.

Any thoughts on this?  I really don't want to screw up production right now and I've made too many changes to keep track of to revert to where the code was stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go through that much trouble:

```
git checkout master              # get the 'bad' version
git branch bad-master            # make a new branch called 'bad-master', cut off master's current state
git fetch                        # make sure you're up to date with the remote
git reset --hard origin/master   # reset your master branch to origin/master's state
<work work work>
git checkout bad-master          # when you're ready to work on bad-master again
```

Note that `git reset --hard origin/master` will discard any work in your working tree that you haven't checked in... so if you've got work you haven't committed yet, be sure to `git stash` it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely normal situation to wind up in, and one you can easily recover from.

All you need to do is:

1. Create a new branch pointing to **your** current version of master

   ```
   git checkout -b my-feature-branch
   ```
2. Reset **your** master to the same thing as origin/master

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard origin/master
   ```

That's it. Now your master is the same as it was before you did your feature development, and you have a feature branch set aside which you can later checkout to resume development.